# What model of Cannondale road bike is this

Tags: road, cannondale

I'm seeking a road bike in my size and this one is (47-49cm). Seller knows nothing about bikes and doesn't know the model, year, or materials. It's a Cannondale, all original except seat and pedals.

[image: cannondale road]

Comment: The model is a Synapse. 2013? Aluminium with carbon fork. 105 groupset.

Comment: How did the seller end up having it?

Comment: Aside - it is suspicious and sketchy that someone is selling a bike and has no idea about anything.   Excuses like "someone gave it to me" are suspect.   You could ask for the serial number (probably stamped under the bottom bracket or into the chainstay on a cannoodle) and trust your instincts.  There will always be other bikes if something smells bad about this one.

Comment: Not a dupe, but there are a lot of relevant points on avoiding buying a stolen bike at https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/743/what-should-i-look-for-when-buying-a-used-bicycle

Comment: "Seller knows nothing..." would make me back off, screams illicit!

Comment: I agree with proceeding with caution, but if my wife went to sell any of our bikes (perhaps after my passing), she would know nothing. Even if I'd spent _hours_ raving about all the details.

Comment: I urge you to have a look at this question: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/74549/is-my-rim-cracked the questions seems not related to yours, but it will be, especially after reading updates #2 and followings.

Answer (score 9):

It's a [2014 Synapse Womens 5 105](https://www.cannondale.com/-/media/files/manual-uploads/manuals/14_c_cusa_bike_catalog_womens.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That's definitely it.

Comment: Its a Synapse 2014 for sure.I bought one for my girlfriend.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Cannondale's models well. However, I have some approximate guesses about roughly what type of bike this and what year.

Due to the lighting, we can't see the exact componentry. I can't read the component model name on the rear derailleur. It could be an 11s 105 (3rd from top, and this one would be the generation released in 2015 if it is one), 10s Tiagra (one step down from 105), or 9s Sora, or possibly 8s Claris (these are in descending order of price). The front derailleur looks like the same generation. I think that the rim brakes make it a bit more likely to be a model earlier than 2018, as even the entry level models had started to transition to disc brakes. The fact that you have brake cables under the bar tape and what looks like internal down tube routing is consistent with this. In any case, I'd guess between 2015 and 2018.

The frame looks like an aluminum one. I would infer this because the carbon frames tend to be pricier, and Cannondale would be less likely to substitute a budget crankset in, and because I think I can see weld lines by the head tube. The CAAD series of aluminum frames generally have level top tubes, whereas you have a sloping top tube. It's possible this is a Synapse. Those were made in aluminum and carbon. Versions equipped with 105 exist, as do versions with Tiagra and Claris.

We don't give bicycle valuations per our FAQ. I'm not sure how much I trust Bicycle Blue Book's prices, because the used bicycle market is thinner than the used car market (so poorer price discovery). However, here's [their page for the 2016 Cannondale Synapse 7 Sora](https://www.bicyclebluebook.com/value-guide/product/3059397/), which does look a bit like this bike. I think bikes with this specification would have retailed for about US$1,000-1500 when new.

The Synapse is an endurance road bike. That is, an all-purpose road bike for leisure or sporty riding, and it actually won't really slow you down in a race if you decide you actually want to do road racing (which is not necessary to enjoy the sport, just offered as an example of what you can do with that bike). Basically, this is a perfectly fine beginner's road bike. If you don't like the sport, you can sell it to someone who might. I suspect it may lack mounts for racks (on which you can mount panniers to carry stuff) or fenders (for riding in the rain, remembering that many of us don't usually do this).

Comment: Wow, thank you! I am probably going to view the bike so I'll know more about the components, but you answered my most important questions: Is it a decent beginner's road bike (yes), and is it overpriced (yes, very). I used to ride about 10 years ago and had a Specialized Dolce that I liked quite a lot, as well as a Surly steel road bike.

Comment: For a new or returning road-bike rider, the expected extra comfort of an endurance bike could be beneficial compared to a more aggressive posture

Comment: @Kate Actually, I did *not* answer if it's overpriced, because a) we don't do valuations here, as stated in our FAQ and b) I don't know what the seller is asking, anyway. If you want to go there, you could check eBay and Facebook marketplace for sales of similar Cannondales (Synapses, preferably with 105, probably years 2013-2018 or so, make sure you look at rim brake Synapses). You could check similar bike models also, e.g. from 2016, Specialized Allez (unisex) or Amira (women's specific) from similar years, Giant Defy, Liv Avail

Answer (score 1):

In many jurisdictions, you do not commit a crime by buying a stolen good if you honestly think it is not the result of a criminal action.

However, with this answer, I am exactly warning you that such a good bike sold by someone having no clue about it apart reading the obvious brand name ***it may be stolen***, unless the contrary is somehow proven, i.e.:

- the seller provides you with the serial number;
- the seller provides you a receipt of the time he/she bought it, or it shows the will of providing a written sales agreement (it can be just a hand written undersigned piece of paper "I, Bike Eisenhower, residing in the White house around the corner, confirm that I sold a B-29 bike to Kate");

So good luck, it may be a good deal, or you may be providing an incentive to bikes thieves in general.

Disclaimer: I am not morally judging you, I just do not want to give any incentives to bike thieves. Yes, someone else will buy it, but: the less demand (willingly or honestly ignoring its provenance) there is for a certain good ("stolen bikes") the less rentable it will be the commerce of such good ("stealing bikes").

Comment: Anyway in most jurisdictions, even when unknowingly buying a stolen good, you may be compelled by law to hand it back to the rightful owner if they claim it. You cannot lawfully own a stolen item.

Comment: @Carel, it can be even worse. For example in Switzerland: you are the buyer of a stolen thing (for example a car) from a shop, but the shop did not know it was stolen, you as the new buyer have to give back the stolen object to the owner **but** the shop can keep the money. Unbelievably absurd. But real.